# Network Solutions alias on Gmail: TLS Negotiation failed, the certificate doesn't match the host

Tags: smtp, gmail, network-solutions

As of yesterday, I can't send any emails with gmail as my alias with network solutions. Has anyone found a fix for this?

I get the error on gmail:

Message not delivered
You're sending this from a different address or alias using the 'Send mail as' feature. The settings for your 'Send mail as' account are misconfigured or out of date. Check those settings and try resending.

TLS Negotiation failed, the certificate doesn't match the host.

Comment: Probably you have the same problem: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/38789651

Answer (score 1):

Try to enter to https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha 
in your browser.

I have no idea what this link do and why , but after i use it  this strange tls problem was gone